# LWJGL applet not loading

Tags: java, lwjgl

I created an Applet with LWJGL. It runs all fine when use run as Applet in eclipse.

I exported the jar file by right-clicking the project and then export and just going through the windows.

When I try to load it in my webbrowser I see a java screen loading, then just all white with nothing happening. It should show me a yellow background.

This is how I load my applet in the html:

```
<applet code="com.game.engine.Main"
archive="test.jar"
width="1024" height="786">
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Working with applets are pretty hard.
You have to make sure you export it as a JAR file and not as a Runnable JAR File.
Also you have to extract all the libraries you're using in to the JAR file.

I hope this cleared a bit up!

Comment: @timodegroot in eclipse i choose the option jar file not runnable jar file. and i included the libraries for lwjgl in my build path.

Comment: Have you included the natives as well? Try using JarSplice: http://ninjacave.com/jarsplice

Comment: i got it to work. the problem was that the way i created the applet was wrong. i needed to use this: <applet code="org.lwjgl.util.applet.AppletLoader" archive="lwjgl_util_applet.jar, lzma.jar" codebase="." width="1024" height="786">. and then add the jar file to the al_jars param. thnx for helping :)